# Add download button to a gtsummary table in RMarkdown HTML file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm building an HTML file in RMarkdown, here's some reproductible data:

```
theme_gtsummary_language(
  language = "pt",
  decimal.mark = ",",
  big.mark = ".")

data <- data.frame(
  anoobito = sample(2019:2023),
  NOME_MUNICIPIO = sample(c("Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo", "Araruama", "Queimados"), 23000, replace = TRUE)
)

data %>%
  select(anoobito, NOME_MUNICIPIO) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = anoobito,
              label = c(NOME_MUNICIPIO ~ "Município de Residência")) %>%
  add_overall(last = T) %>%
  modify_table_body(fun = ~ dplyr::arrange(.x, desc(readr::parse_number(stat_0, 
                                                                        locale = readr::locale(decimal_mark = ","))))) %>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1":"stat_5") ~ "**Ano do Óbito**") %>%
  modify_header(label = "**Município de Residência**") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  remove_row_type(type = "header")
```

I'm using gtsummary to get summary statistics. I want to add a "download" button to the table, so people can export the table in .csv or .xlxs format. Is that possible? I know the `DT` package allows downloading data, but can I do that to a gtsummary table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [{downloadthis}](https://cran.r-project.org/package=downloadthis) package you can add a button after your table (to download the original data ; not sure if this is what you want or the summary):

````
```{r}
library(writexl)
library(downloadthis)
data <- iris
```
    
```{r}
f <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")
write_xlsx(data, f)
download_file(
  path = f,
  output_name = "data",
  button_label = "Get data (*.xlsx)",
  button_type = "primary",
  has_icon = TRUE,
  self_contained = TRUE)
```
````

If you want the  summary, you can first assign your table to `gt_table`, before displaying it, and save it:

```
gt_table %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() %>% 
  write_xlsx("summary.xlsx")
```

and work from this file